# rvm install 1.8.7-head errors on centos 5.5

Tags: ruby, installation, centos, rvm

I installed rvm successfully as a root on CentOS 5.5.
Then I tried to to install ruby-1.8.7-head

> rvm install 1.8.7-head

And receive such error

> Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
>
> ruby-1.8.7-head - #fetching 
>   Cloning from [github url], this may take a while depending on your connection...
>   Initialized empty Git repository in /usr/local/rvm/repos/ruby-1.8.7-head/.git/
>   error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing [github url]
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed
>   cloning from [github.com/ruby.git] failed, now attempting to clone from https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git, this may take a while depending on your connection...
>   Initialized empty Git repository in /usr/local/rvm/repos/ruby-1.8.7-head/.git/
>   error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing [github.com/ruby/ruby.git/info/refs]
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed
>   ERROR: There has been an error while trying to fetch the repository.
>   Halting the installation.
>   ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TO FIX THIS ISSUE

(Optional) backup certificates

> cp /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt /root/backup/

Get new cert

> curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

After that I got stuck with next error

> rvm install 1.8.7-head

Here it is

> Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
>
> ruby-1.8.7-head - #fetching 
>   HEAD is now at 61ac67c merge revision(s) 31731:31734:
>   From https://github.com/ruby/ruby
>    * branch            ruby_1_8_7 -> FETCH_HEAD
>   Already up-to-date.
>   Copying from repo to src path...
>   Running autoreconf
>   ERROR: Error running 'autoreconf', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-head/autoreconf.log
>   ERROR: Skipping configure step, 'configure' does not exist, did autoreconf not run successfully?
>   ruby-1.8.7-head - #compiling 
>   ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-head/make.log
>   ERROR: There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

Comment: That problem was resolved by installing Autoconf 2.60 with such commands:

>wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.63.tar.gz

>tar xvzf autoconf-2.63.tar.gz

>cd autoconf-2.63

>./configure --prefix=/usr

>make

>make install

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 11.04 `apt-get install automake` fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you chrismealy, but your answer is not usefull for Centos :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out "rvm notes" and make sure you install all the dependencies listed for your system. It sounds to me like you are missing libssl-dev, however you may be missing more than that.

Comment: Thank you. Actually The reason I've posted a question here is that I have solved my issue and it wasn't a trivial answer for me. I just wanted to share my experience. There are some rules at stackoverflow which deny posting an answer to own question at once :)