# Downloading RVM Errors

Tags: ruby, rvm

I tried to download RVM and I got this error message:

> error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
>   verify failed
>
> More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a
>   "bundle"  of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). The
>   default  bundle is named curl-ca-bundle.crt; you can specify an
>   alternate file  using the `--cacert` option. If this HTTPS server uses
>   a certificate signed by a CA represented in  the bundle, the
>   certificate verification probably failed due to a  problem with the
>   certificate (it might be expired, or the name might  not match the
>   domain name in the URL). If you'd like to turn off curl's verification
>   of the certificate, use  the `-k` (or `--insecure`) option.

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Which command did you use to download RVM?

Comment: This is the command I used: $ curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6241614/604041 ?

Comment: Hey Sammy I tried putting curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt into the terminal and here is what happened: arning: Failed to create the file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0  209k    0  1222    0     0   2979      0  0:01:11 --:--:--  0:01:11  2979
curl: (23) Failed writing body

Comment: Simply add `-k` to `curl` and it won't fail for bad SSL certificate checkings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curl Certificate Error when Using RVM to install Ruby 1.9.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414232/curl-certificate-error-when-using-rvm-to-install-ruby-1-9-2)

Comment: Thanks karatedog so what would the line be with -k included?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the output and follow instructions!

Alternatively if you do not care for security, do this:

```
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```

and btw. it's duplicate question! (and my answer)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like they recently changed the command. Try this:

```
    bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

You could probably add `-k` to your command too. I think their cert is bad. Github's is fine.

Comment: Hey Nick when I use that command it just takes me to the next line and nothing happens.

Comment: Since when is that the latest command? Neither the RVM site nor the GitHub repo Readme uses that.

Comment: This is the same as `curl https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable`, it is just a different syntax. And the latter is on the RVM site (Installing RVM, bottom of page)

Comment: Sorry! Forgot the part about making rvm actually accessible from your vm. Are you saying the first command doesn't even run a script?

Comment: Now I'm confused. What exactly should I be entering into the Terminal?

Comment: it's not the same command it uses `-s` which just silences errors

Comment: Umm, no we do NOT show using  bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer) - The last one you showed is merely what the full command actually is, since the get.rvm.io is a redirect which we clearly spell out. The first one you posted is not on our install page at all actually. What we say is: "You could also use full path for the installer: " and we detail what that full path is. 'curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable' is the *correct* command as we show all over the install page.

Comment: @deryldoucette: I never said it was the latest command. I said that what appears on the page NOW (get.rvm.io) is different from what it once was (the command I posted, circa last month). I'm using the command I posted in a script to initialize VM's with rvm.

Comment: @ppeyer: It sounds like your root problem is that you're not accepting their ssl cert. Try this: curl -kL get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

Comment: Hey Nick here is what that command gave me: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  9219  100  9219    0     0  12799      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 95041
BASH 3.2.25 required (you have 3.2.17(1)-release)

Comment: @ppreyer OK! That's what you should get for the first line, but it should spit out a bunch more into your shell as it downloads everything else. It sounds like your bash shell is too old from the error message? What OS are you running? Are you doing this in cygwin by any chance?